# Why can I not use my setter for a custom element in pure JS with Template?

Tags: javascript, web-component, shadow-dom

I am fairly new to web components, and have been trying to figure out how the things work. When doing the recommended process of creating a template, then cloning it into my `shadowRoot` I can see them in my chrome elements, but not on the webpage itself.

For example:

```
import './components/ingredients/ingredients-table';

const template = document.createElement('template');
template.innerHTML = `
    <h3>Add some ingredients</h3>
    <ingredients-table id="hehe"></ingredients-table>

`

class App extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this._shadowRoot = this.attachShadow({ mode: 'open' });
        this._shadowRoot.appendChild(template.content.cloneNode(true));
    }

    connectedCallback() {
        console.log(this._shadowRoot.querySelector('ingredients-table').id)
        this._shadowRoot.querySelector('ingredients-table').ingredients = [
            "1 tbsp, cinnamon extract",
            "2 tbsp, cinnamon extract",
            "3 tbsp, cinnamon extract",
            "4 tbsp, cinnamon extract",
            "5 tbsp, cinnamon extract",
            "6 tbsp, cinnamon extract",
        ];
    }
}

window.customElements.define('main-app', App);

window.addEventListener('load', () => {
    const main = document.querySelector('main');
    const app = document.createElement('main-app');
    main.appendChild(app);

});
```

This shows
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Za2w9.png) which in turn means that `<ingredients-table>`'s set function isn't working

But when I change constructor line `this._shadowRoot.appendChild(template.content.cloneNode(true));` to

```
this._shadowRoot.innerHTML = `
    <h3>Add some ingredients</h3>
    <ingredients-table id="hehe"></ingredients-table>
`
```

I get [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Btv2F.png)

Can someone please clarify how this exactly works? Thank you

Here is a codepen: 
https://codepen.io/aishmitkhurana/pen/wvaKWBL?editors=0010

Answer (score 0):

#### Your error is a (simple) typo

After digging through your CodePen
https://codepen.io/aishmitkhurana/pen/wvaKWBL?editors=0010

**your code:**

```
const template = document.createElement('template');
template.innerHTML =  `
    <h3>Add some ingredients</h3>
    <ingredients-table></ingredients-table>
    <recipe-steps></recipe-steps>`

...more code...

const template2 = document.createElement('template');
template  <--TYPO    .innerHTML = `
    <table>
        <ingredients-list></ingredients-list>
        <tr>
            <input
                id="ingredients-input"
                placeholder="e.g. 3/4 tbsp cinnamon powder"
            >
        </tr>
    </table>`
```

Your are assigning the **second HTML** to the **first** *template*

Your F12 Dev Console clearly says:

[image]

for the line:

```
this._shadowRoot.querySelector('ingredients-table').ingredients =
```

because there is no <ingredients-table> element in the **EMPTY** template2

Comment: sorry for the late reply, i posted a codepen. the two components are not using templates as you can see, but if you were to uncomment those lines instead of directly setting innerHTML (which I heard is not as efficient?) it does not work

Comment: so i just fixed that issue, but that was not what i was curious about. as you can see i have commented out the innerHTML setting of the shadowRoot of App, and used the cloneNode to set it. This does not work here. Can you please see why this does not work?

Comment: `set ingredients(ingredients) {}` is simply never called, you can see this with the console.log not being printed in it

Comment: Use the debugger to step through your code (I have NOT done that!). Especially pay attention to what goes on in ``constructors``. You can't do DOM operations in the ``constructor`` because the elements are added LATER in the ``connectedCallback``. Also create proper/valid HTML for the TABLE.. rows go in table, TDs go in TRs.  Start small and only add more code when your existing code works. success (I am working on my own projects, so don't have more time to spend on your problems)